# Cfchart : Cluster of Stacked Bars

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfchart

I have the following data which I need to display as a cluster of stacked chart for each month.
[image: Data for CfChart]

The chart should have two stacked bars for each month.

- One would be a stacked bar chart of Historical_A and Historical_B
- Other one would be for Monthly_A and Monthly_B.

I need to have the chart displayed as per this 
[Example Link](http://excelhelphq.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Example-of-Cluster-Stacked-Chart.png).

I have been trying to manipulate the `webchart` XML as below but nothing has come out of it so far.

```
    <elements action="" place="Stacked"  drawOutline="false">
            <morph morph="Grow"/>
            <series place="default" index="0"  shape="bar">
                <paint color="#E48701"/>
            </series>
            <series index="1" place="stacked"  shape="bar">
                <paint color="#A5BC4E"/>
            </series>
            <series index="2" place="default" shape="bar">
                <paint color="#1B95D9"/>
            </series>
            <series index="3" place="stacked"  shape="bar">
                <paint color="#CACA9E"/>
            </series>
    </elements>
```

Edit 1 : Found a similar chart in Highcharts. [HighCharts Example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped)

Comment: So maybe just use high charts then?

Comment: Ditto to @Sean 's suggestion. I suspect webcharts3d does not support that particular kind of combination chart. No examples of it anyway. The closest I could find was three "clustered" bars, with one "default" series.

Comment: I just wanted to ensure `webcharts` doesn't support this combination before going the `Highcharts` way. Thanks all for the advice.

Comment: I cannot say with 100% certainty, but based on your tests (and mine) it sure does not seem like it. As soon as you try and combine clustered and stacked, it switches all four series to stacked.